# Best way to store an article's state in my database?

Tags: database, database-design

Right now I've got articles that can have a `state`. The `state` currently can either be:

- `published`
- `draft`

I'm trying to decide the best way to store the data and would like to feedback on either approach.

**Version 1** (Emphasis on semantics):

ex: `state` with an enum of `['draft', 'published']`

**Version 2** (Emphasis on performance):

ex: `published` with a boolean.

The second version DRY's up my client a little bit, since the logic for the first version gets messy as I save the state in constant variables.

```
export const ARTICLE_STATE_DRAFT = 1;
export const ARTICLE_STATE_PUBLISHED = 2;

export const ARTICLE_STATE_TYPES = {
  [ARTICLE_STATE_DRAFT]: 'draft',
  [ARTICLE_STATE_PUBLISHED]: 'published'
};
```

What's a better pattern and why?

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion would be go with

Store the state values  in separate table and give the reference to the parent table as foreign key .

The advantage of this would be you can handle the state with one column ( say `"current_state"` ) in the `articles` table  .

If you introduce a new state to the article ,  you can handle this with this design , whereas this will not be case in other approach as you need to add another column .

Hope this helps